# I want to use MPAndroidChart swift library in Objective C

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, swift, mpandroidchart

I want to implement the MPAndroidChart library which is in Swift,
and I have developed my app in Objective-C.
I need to implement that library in my existing Objective-C app.
Please guide me step by step.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can easily use Swift in your Objective C project.

> A Swift class or protocol must be marked with the @objc attribute to be accessible and usable in Objective-C. This attribute tells the compiler that this piece of Swift code can be accessed from Objective-C. If your Swift class is a descendant of an Objective-C class, the compiler automatically adds the @objc attribute for you

Check this Apple doc:
https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/BuildingCocoaApps/MixandMatch.html